# css half bordered circle with transparent shapes on it

Tags: html, css, svg, canvas

I need a circle with half border from bottom,I want to fill this circle with color by percentage.

I need to put another circle on that but center of other circle has a transparent shapes on it.

First at all i need a circle with half border, then put another circle on it with transparent shapes

Is there a easier way for example with canvas ?

What i need:
[image]

```css
    .circle {
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      margin-left: 0;
      border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
      border-radius: 100%;
      background-color: transparent;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -moz-align-items: center;
      -ms-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .example {
       background: linear-gradient(transparent 20%, #00EFAF 20%);
    }
```

```html
 <div class="circle example" data-fill="50">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mask combined with gradient to achieve this:

```css
.box {
  --b: 10px; /* 10px of visible border */

  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:linear-gradient(transparent calc(100% - var(--fill)),#00EFAF 0);
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(99.5% - var(--b)),#fff calc(100% - var(--b)));
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(99.5% - var(--b)),#fff calc(100% - var(--b)));
}

body {
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--fill:20%"></div>
<div class="box" style="--fill:50%;--b:20px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--fill:80%;--b:5px;"></div>
```

[image: CSS half bordered circle]

Use it as pseudo element to easily add content inside:

```css
.box {
  --b: 10px; /* 10px of visible border */

  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  display:inline-flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size:30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:linear-gradient(transparent calc(100% - var(--fill)),#00EFAF 0);
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(99.5% - var(--b)),#fff calc(100% - var(--b)));
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(99.5% - var(--b)),#fff calc(100% - var(--b)));
}

body {
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--fill:20%">20%</div>
<div class="box" style="--fill:50%;--b:20px;">50%</div>
<div class="box" style="--fill:80%;--b:5px;">80%</div>
```

[image: CSS circle with gradient border]

In case you want to perform animation you can adjust the linear-gradient like below

```css
.box {
  --b: 10px; /* 10px of visible border */

  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  display:inline-flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size:30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:linear-gradient(#00EFAF,#00EFAF) content-box;
  padding-top:calc(100% - var(--fill));
  transition:0.5s;
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(99.5% - var(--b)),#fff calc(100% - var(--b)));
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(99.5% - var(--b)),#fff calc(100% - var(--b)));
}

.box:hover::before {
  padding-top:0%;
}

body {
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--fill:20%">20%</div>
<div class="box" style="--fill:50%;--b:20px;">50%</div>
<div class="box" style="--fill:80%;--b:5px;">80%</div>
```

---

Here is another idea using `clip-path`

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  display:inline-flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size:30px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border:var(--b,10px) solid #00EFAF;
  border-radius:50%;
  clip-path:
    polygon(0   calc(100% - var(--fill)),
           100% calc(100% - var(--fill)),
           100% 100%,
           0    100%);
  transition:0.5s;
}
.box:hover::before {
  clip-path:
    polygon(0   0,
           100% 0,
           100% 100%,
           0    100%);

}
body {
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--fill:20%">20%</div>
<div class="box" style="--fill:50%;--b:20px;">50%</div>
<div class="box" style="--fill:80%;--b:5px;">80%</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but if u check my image again, my circle shape filled with color not the borders only.I should put another circle on that parent circle shape (which filled blue) which has transparent squares, I need the new circle and transparent shapes too! I am new to css and i cant solve that problem.

Comment: @Rmanx77I gave the border part now you only need to put your other element above it and fill it with blue. Share you other shape with its transparent part and will add it to the code

Comment: I wonder, Why mask and not put the radial gradient as the first background ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak the mask is for the transparency, if we add it as background we need to match the main background. It's a solution if transparency is not needed